# IF statement containing OR perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

A very simple question but I can't seem to figure out the problem. Why does this snippet of code successfully print all lines where $F[1] does not equal 83:

```
    if ($F[1] != 83) {
        print OUT2 "$_\n";
    }
```

But this snippet (containing an OR statement) simply prints all lines, ignoring both criteria:

```
    if ($F[1] != 83 || $F[1] != 99) {
        print OUT2 "$_\n";
    }
```

The desired result was to print all lines where $F[1] contains anything other than 83 or 99.

Comment: Use AND then, like `if ($F[1] != 83 && $F[1] != 99)...`

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood and thought AND would look for conditions where $F[1] was equal to both 83 and 99 - which is nonsensical. Is it necessary to restate the variable being tested or can it be shortened to something like `$F[1] != 83 or 99`?

Comment: instead OR is nonsensical, since *every* number is either != 83 or != 99 or both

Comment: True! Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every number is either != 83 or != 99 or both, using `||` won't work.

Use `&&` instead to get only numbers other than 83 and 99:

```
if ( $F[1] != 83 && $F[1] != 99 ) {
```

If you have a longer list to check, you may want to do e.g.:

```
if ( ! grep $_ == $F[1], 83, 99, 107, 133, 150 ) {
```

Answer (score 6):

Never forget the following logical rules:

```
(not (A and B)) == (not(A) or  not(B))

(not (A or B))  == (not(A) and not(B))
```

Comment: Nice, short, to the point. I happily upvote this.